# module not defined in Vue Project

Tags: vue.js, node-modules, tailwind-css

I just created a new Vue app by running `npm init vue@latest` like specified in the [official documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/quick-start.html). Then I tried adding Tailwind to my app by following the [guide for Vue & Vite](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/vite) on their website. However, when opening the file `tailwind.config.js` I noticed that ESLint tells me that `module` is not defined and the `module.exports` syntax does not work.

Why is that and how can I fix it?

Edit: The default `.eslintrc.cjs` file that gets created by Vue looks like this:

```js
/* eslint-env node */
require("@rushstack/eslint-patch/modern-module-resolution");

module.exports = {
  root: true,
  extends: [
    "plugin:vue/vue3-essential",
    "eslint:recommended",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier",
  ],
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: "latest",
  },
};
```

Comment: You'll need to share more info, include your `.eslintrc.js` in your question.

Comment: I edited my question. Also: Vue created a `.eslintrc.cjs` not `.js` file. Is that the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this to `.eslintrc.cjs`

```js
env: {
  node: true,
},
```

so your file will look like

```js
/* eslint-env node */
require("@rushstack/eslint-patch/modern-module-resolution");

module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    node: true,
  },
  extends: [
    "plugin:vue/vue3-essential",
    "eslint:recommended",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier",
  ],
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: "latest",
  },
};
```

You can add any of [these](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/user-guide/configuring/language-options#specifying-environments) values

Comment: Alternatively, you can also use the comment `/* eslint-env node */` in the affected files. This is just a per-file based variant of the accepted answer, but I wanted to mention it for completeness sake.

Comment: @muell true. You're welcome to edit the answer

Answer (score 1):

Consider to use

- `.eslintrc.cjs`

  ```js
  …
    overrides: [
      {
        files: ["{vue,vite}.config.*"],
        env: {
          node: true,
        },
      },
    ],
  ```

as well as setting `compilerOptions.types: ["node"]` TS option only for those files.

> **This is necessary** to ensure that I'm not using NodeJS API in sourcecode and doesn't pulling polyfills on it.

---

This is how it might looks like:

- `.eslintrc.cjs`

  ```
  /* eslint-env node */
  require("@rushstack/eslint-patch/modern-module-resolution");

  module.exports = {
    root: true,
    extends: [
      "plugin:vue/vue3-essential",
      "eslint:recommended",
      "@vue/eslint-config-typescript",
      "@vue/eslint-config-prettier",
    ],
    overrides: [
      {
        files: ["cypress/e2e/**/*.{cy,spec}.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}"],
        extends: ["plugin:cypress/recommended"],
      },
      {
        files: ["{vue,vite}.config.*"],
        env: {
          node: true,
        },
      },
    ],
    parserOptions: {
      ecmaVersion: "latest",
    },
  };
  ```
- `tsconfig.config.json`

  ```json
  {
    "extends": "@vue/tsconfig/tsconfig.node.json",
    "include": ["vue.config.*", "vite.config.*", "vitest.config.*", "cypress.config.*", "playwright.config.*"],
    "compilerOptions": {
      "composite": true,
      "types": ["node"]
    }
  }
  ```